# Google Cloud IAM adding large number of users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am adding a large number of users to my project from the organization into my project. The organization is managed by my University and I cannot directly access users from there. I have to manually type email select the user and add it.

Is there any way I can automate this process by using cloud SDK on Windows, by writing some program OR any web automation tool which search through emails and add them?

I have a pattern of emails but not exact emails. So this searches through this pattern and adds all those which exists in organization IAM to my project OR just search through and give me the list of emails.

GCloud IAM Scenario:

- Organization managed by University having all users in it.
- I am a user with limited access
- I have created my own project under this organization I cannot access the organization IAM dashboard
  and through CLI
- But when I start typing an email in add member window in my project
  it gives all    matching users list
- I want to grasp all these emails.

Comment: I have a list of emails about 1,200,000 from which some are valid and I don't know which are...
If I add using this list and it just checks if this is in the organization before adding...

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand your situation,

Firstly, you need to have at least permissions

> - resourcemanager.projects.get
> - resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
> - resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy

You could ask your administrator to grant you role named

> - Project IAM Admin (roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin)
> - Security Admin (roles/iam.securityAdmin)

From my opinions, you should write a bash shell that allow you to loop your user email address and add each member to grant permission by this command

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
--member=user:my-user@example.com --role=roles/viewer
```

in this case:
`my-project` is your project name
`my-user@example.com` is an email your want to grant for
`roles/viewer` is role name you want to grant to user

Comment: If I can ask them to assign a role then there was no problem...

I have to do this on my own...

I have a list of emails but not all valid...   I can add them into my project by typing them...

is there any way so that instead of typing each I run a script or automation software like Selenium IDE which add checks valid email and add it to the project...

When I type invalid email it gives this error

Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, G Suite account, or Cloud Identity account.

Comment: I want that to iterate over the list of emails find valid and add to my project.

Comment: So, you have 2 stories
- Add list users to google cloud IAM
- Iterate over the user list and check which email is live or not, right ?

Comment: I have list of emails...    I want to check which emails are live and then add live emails to my project